# How can i add nerfonts icons to my website?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I'm used to use Awesome-fonts, but I found the nerdfonts website and I want to use the nerdfonts icons but I dont know how.

I tried to use the icon class like "nf-custom-c" but the icon doesn't appear

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend new users visit [ask] for tips on forming their questions in a way that best enables the community to provide assistance. There is probably not enough detail here for much help to be given. I'd recommend reading up on how to create a [mcve] and include some code, any errors you are seeing, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderNied ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download the [css sheet](https://www.nerdfonts.com/assets/css/webfont.css) and the [symbols font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v3.0.2/NerdFontsSymbolsOnly.zip)
Add those to your site and link to the css from your html
Change the src of the css to direct to the font file
Use `<i class="nf <class>"></i>` e.g. `<i class="nf nf-custom-c"></i>`